# randomly generating a enum value for two players

Tags: c, random, enums

I am new at this and trying to set up a game board where two players are randomly assigned colors:

```
enum colour
{
P_RED, P_WHITE
};
```

Which

```
struct player
{
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];
enum colour col;
};
```

is to be used to pass the information. I get that rand() should be used to generate a random color for one player and the second player to be assigned the remaining color but I am unsure how to go about it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg odd/even only checks the lowest bit, and LCG's (which rand is) are known to have poor distributional properties in the low bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random integer.  If it's greater than `RAND_MAX / 2`, make one assignment.  Otherwise, make the other assignment.

Note that `rand` is a very bad random number generator.  I'd recommend using `random` at the least, or downloading Mersenne Twister and incorporating it.

Comment: On most systems, `rand` and `random` are the same these days. Also, `rand` is in the C specification, while `random` is a platform-specific extension.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [securecoding](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MSC30-C.+Do+not+use+the+rand()+function+for+generating+pseudorandom+numbers) says otherwise.  It's true that `rand` is omnipresent while `random` is POSIX, but my main point is that OP should make an effort to step away from `rand` because it's a very poor PRNG.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `rand` and `random` are the same on only in the glibc (ie not in BSD, mac, non-glibc linux, ...), while `random` is available on every POSIX system